# Typescript allowing variables to pollute global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

It seems that TypeScript is allowing variables from other files to pollute the global namespace. Or, at least, where I would expect definition errors to take place before runtime, they don't.

Consider these two files:

```js
/* file1.ts */

const SomeVar = 'Hi'
```

```js
/* file2.ts */

console.log(SomeVar)
```

In VsCode, I would expect an error in `file2.ts` as I have neither exported the `const` from `file1.ts`, nor have I imported it. When I run the node program, I do indeed get a runtime error, but this means that VsCode is giving a false positive by not throwing a linting error.

Note that there is no error under `SomeVar` in VsCode:

[image]

Is there a reason why variables aren't being scoped to their files for the linter in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install a linter extension for vscode, tslint for example.

Comment: tslint has [long been deprecated](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/02/tslint-deprecated-eslint/)